# file name extension capitalization is being altered

Tags: command-line, mate

I have a directory with a file named `SLOTS.nc`
If, in mate terminal, I type `ls SLOTS*` I see the file.

If I type `ls slots*` I do not, this is all OK.

But, if I type `ls SLOTS.NC`, the file is displayed as `SLOTS.NC`  -- This file does NOT EXIST.

So, first it is matching the extension (part after ".") with both cases, and then reporting the file extension capitalized.

This makes it VERY difficult to use mv and cp commands to alter the file name extension.

My OS is Ubuntu 17.10, kernel 4.13.0-43, and the desktop environment is mate 1.18.0

Is there any way to turn off this manipulation of file extension capitalization?

OK, gets MUCH wierder!  This ONLY happens when the file is residing on a USB thumb drive!  That one is formatted as W95 FAT32.  Everything works exactly as expected when on the system disk.

Thanks for any comments,

Jon

Comment: really? not your mistake?

Comment: Yes, this all makes sense, of course, but there IS a file on there called SLOTS.nc, so it DOES have both upper and lower case in the stored file names.  It seems to only be when MATCHING files that the extension is tried in both cases.  And, when doing ls, the file is printed to match the case it was asked for, which is NOT the actual name of the file.  Confused the HECK out of me!  Thanks!

Comment: @dessert Done! I have turned my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## W95 FAT32 is not case sensitive but is *[case preserving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Case_preservation)*

This means FAT32 cannot have two files with names like `SLOTS.nc` and `SLOTS.NC`. However, if you name your file `SLOTS.nc`, the system will preserve that information.

I am not sure why `ls slots*` does not work with `SLOTS.nc` in `FAT32` file system. This has to do with bash expanding the `*`.

But any case combination of the full file name such as `ls SlOtS.nS` returns that specific case combination when the file system is FAT32.

Here is a similar question in the [Superuser site](https://superuser.com/questions/431342/linux-both-case-sensitive-and-case-insensitive-and-always-inconvenient) you may find useful.

## This is not an issue with native files systems used by Ubuntu such as `ext4`

`ext4` and other files systems natively used by Ubuntu are case sensitive. That is, `SLOTS.ns` and `SlOtS.nS` are completely separate files.

Hope this helps